# obtain a list of available dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How can I check the names of available dataframes in pandas?

with a loop I create several dataframes and I would like to check if all the desidered df are created

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have `DataFrame` imported, you can simply do

```
[name for name, obj in locals().items() if isinstance(obj, DataFrame)]
```

Comment: You could also use `isinstance(obj, pd.DataFrame)`

Comment: Yep, I did feel I was missing something. Thanks @James.